# How to check if a view wasn't touched for a specific time

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view and i want it to do something when the user stops touching it for more then 500 milliseconds.

How can i check this?

I was thinking of having a thread polling the current millisecond time and checking it with the last touch.

is there a better approach with out polling?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the user stop touching the view you can open a postdelayed thread for 500ms , in the runnable of the last perform a check if the view has been touched during this period (using a Boolean flag) , if not make the needed operation.

Comment: what do you mean "in the runnable of the last" how do i know what one is the last?

Answer (score 1):

Run a thread that counts 1 for every second, or 1000 for a seconds ( so you have the millis as well) and then just make connection to compare. If u are not touching the UI, u don't need handlers as well I think..

Comment: if the view is custom you can create a method in it to start the counting which will be called from the constructor, otherwise, you just create a method ( or class if you want some more features ) and call it right after the view is drawn ( in onCreate )